# How to show congrats modal after successfully sign up?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails, Devise gem, jQuery validation plugin and Bootstrap.

I can call $('#congrats').show(); when user submit, but it is closing, because user should be automatically redirected after sign up.

Also, I can't call if page is loaded first time, yes ?

What can I do to call show  function at right time ?

**MY HTML FORM**

```
     <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="sign_up" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="W0u6CgL+sA/n/Zecikl67zLqkIPePQz01Vg0u3bi2nc=" /></div>
<div class="field2">

  <label for="user_first_name">First name</label>
  <input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" /></div>

<div class="field2"><label for="user_last_name">Last name</label>
  <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text" /></div>

<div class="field2"><label for="user_email">Email</label>
  <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="" /></div>

<div class="field2"><label for="user_password">Password</label>
  <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" /></div>

<div class="field2"><label for="user_password_confirmation">Re-Type Password</label>
  <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password" />

</div>

<div class="login_submit">
  <input class="btn login" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you just redirect after the user click the `ok` button in your modal form? Where is your code?

Comment: @JRGalia He can, but that's kind of lying to the user since he wouldn't be logged in yet. Except if he really logs the user in using Ajax, but that's an overkill.

Comment: You could just load the modal when the page your re-routed to loads right?

Comment: Also, just a tip, but I would ditch the idea, it would annoy the hell out of me as a user. Simply being re-routed to another page is feedback enough for me to know I successfully logged in.

Comment: @Jeemusu I agree, but only if it's a modal. A flash message would be more suitable imo. :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, anything that jumps in my face and forces me to click a button to proceed is a big nono. A flash message would be fine however.

Comment: guys, this it is not my iniciative to show modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash .. The flash system is in place just to handle such scenarios. The values set in the flash will be persisted only for one redirect. If the user were to refresh the page, the flash value will be automatically unset and the user will not see that message again.

- Your user submits the form.
- Your controller on the backend sets the flash message indicating success. It redirects to the appropriate page.
- Your view code on the redirected page reads the flash message and sets some js variable.
- Your js code on that view reads the previously set variable and depending on the value, displays your congrats modal.

I dont remember erb syntax, but i can write some pseudo code:

```
if flash message["signup_success"] == true, then
   print this text "var showCongrats = true;"
else print this text "var showCongrats = false;"
```

in your js code,

```
$(function() {
   if (showCongrats) { // show the modal; 
   }
})
```

We just want erb to print to the page the variable declaration.

Comment: You want to check if <% if flash[:notice]== "successful sign up" %> call some js , yes ? If yes, can you give an example, because I'm not experienced at calling js from views.

Comment: Updated the answer. You are not calling js from the view. You are using erb to output to the page a javascript variable declaration. Thats it. When your on dom ready js will execute, it just checks whether a global variable named showCongrats has a truthy value. If it does, display the modal.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

- Setting a `logged_in_successfully` session variable to `true` after the user submits the form
- In the layout of the redirected to page, check if that variable is set to true

  - If so, include the *congratz* modal that would ideally be in a partial, otherwise do nothing.
- In the redirected to action, unset the variable `logged_in_successfully`, or set it to `false`.

Comment: Why would you need a session variable? If the user is on that page, I think it's safe to assume that they must be logged in right?

Comment: You can check if the user is logged in, yeah. But you cannot check if he has just logged in (first page view after the login).